# Android Flipboard Style Library

Tags: android, flipboard

I am looking to implement a Flip-board style effect in my android Application application. Is there an Library available

[image]

Comment: try to search in google you will get sure

Comment: Actually, it's not that difficult to do, and much more satisfying when it's your own!  http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

Comment: https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no.
if you want this effect you'll have to make it yourself.